# Ionic redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

After login test, i tried to go to the home page but i have a problem. I used               $location.path("/templates/welcome.html");
but it does not work.

My controller in app.js is :

```
controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

    $scope.login = function(user) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/app_dev.php/json/login/"+user.username+"/"+user.password)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.status);
            if(response.data.status === 200)
            {
                alert("redirect to main page");
                $location.path("/templates/welcome.html");
            }else if(response.data.status === 403){
                alert("Login or password incorrect");
            }else{
                alert("User not found");
            }
        });
    };
})
```

The alert is working but the redirection does not work. In the console i have this error :

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: $location is not defined
    at app.js:37
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject $location into the controller like this

```
controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $location) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not injected $location service in your controller..

Answer (score 0):

I think the probleme is coming from the statProrovider. My state is :

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('signin', {
            url: '/sign-in',
            templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
            controller: 'SignInCtrl'
        })

})
```

In my html page :

```
<div ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
  <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
      </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login(user)">Login</button>
</form>
```

I just started using Ionic that's why